# Is there a way to exclude specific modifiers from evaluation when getting the evaluated depsgraph with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way to exclude specific modifiers from evaluation when running `ID.evaluated_get(depsgraph)`? And if so, how should I do it? Disabling a modifier seems to trigger evaluation one more time for each disabled modifier, which is inefficient.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation re _"Disabling a modifier seems to trigger evaluation one more time for each disabled modifier, which is inefficient."_

Comment: So, when I am disabling the modifier in the stack through UI (doing with Python, but still using the state of UI variable) that triggers Blender to re-evaluate the modifier stack because a depsgraph update is triggered. I was hoping for this sort of pseudocode solution ID.evaluated_get(depsgaph, modifiers_exclude={}) but there seems to be none.